# How to map two table in spring hibernate.cfg.xml

Tags: java, xml, spring, hibernate, spring-mvc

I have two tables (users, vacations). I created two file table.hbm.xml and this is the code:
table.hbm.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE hibernate-mapping PUBLIC
        "-//Hibernate/Hibernate Mapping DTD 3.0//EN"
        "http://www.hibernate.org/dtd/hibernate-mapping-3.0.dtd">
<hibernate-mapping package="com.terafast.manager.model">
    <class name="User" table="users">
        <id name="id" column="USER_ID">
            <generator class="native" />
        </id>
        <property name="username" column="USERNAME" />
        <property name="password" column="PASSWORD" />
        <property name="email" column="EMAIL" />
    </class>

    <class name="Vacation" table="vacations">
        <id name="id" column="REQUEST_ID">
            <generator class="native" />
        </id>
        <property name="who" column="USER_ID" />
        <property name="when" column="START_DATE" />
        <property name="reason" column="REASON" />
        <property name="duration" column="HOW_LONG" />
        <property name="create" column="CREATED_AT" />
        <property name="status" column="STATUS" />
    </class>
</hibernate-mapping>
```

hibernate.cfg.xml

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='utf-8'?>
<!DOCTYPE hibernate-configuration PUBLIC
        "-//Hibernate/Hibernate Configuration DTD 3.0//EN"
        "http://www.hibernate.org/dtd/hibernate-configuration-3.0.dtd">
<hibernate-configuration>        
  <session-factory>
    <property name="dialect">org.hibernate.dialect.MySQLDialect</property>
    <property name="show_sql">true</property>  
    <mapping resource="com/terafast/manager/model/table.hbm.xml"/>
  </session-factory>
</hibernate-configuration>
```

Vacation.hbm.xml (Seperated)

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE hibernate-mapping PUBLIC
        "-//Hibernate/Hibernate Mapping DTD 3.0//EN"
        "http://www.hibernate.org/dtd/hibernate-mapping-3.0.dtd">
<hibernate-mapping package="com.terafast.manager.model">
    <class name="Vacation" table="vacations">
        <id name="id" column="REQUEST_ID">
            <generator class="native" />
        </id>
        <property name="who" column="USER_ID" />
        <property name="when" column="START_DATE" />
        <property name="reason" column="REASON" />
        <property name="duration" column="HOW_LONG" />
        <property name="create" column="CREATED_AT" />
        <property name="status" column="STATUS" />
    </class>
</hibernate-mapping>
```

My web application work with just one table (users). but when I add vacations on table.hbm.xml I got an error.

```
part of an error
SEVERE: Context initialization failed
org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'sessionFactory' defined in ServletContext resource [/WEB-INF/spring/root-context.xml]: Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is org.hibernate.InvalidMappingException: Could not parse mapping document from resource com/terafast/manager/model/table.hbm.xml
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1553)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:539)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:475)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:304)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:228)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:300)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:195)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.preInstantiateSingletons(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:684)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:760)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:482)
    at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader.configureAndRefreshWebApplicationContext(ContextLoader.java:403)
    at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader.initWebApplicationContext(ContextLoader.java:306)
    at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener.contextInitialized(ContextLoaderListener.java:106)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.listenerStart(StandardContext.java:4729)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal(StandardContext.java:5167)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:150)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1409)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1399)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
```

Could somebody explain this?

Comment: why two <class> tags in single hbm file. You got to seperate them in two files

Comment: I will try that but how should define them in hibernate.cfg.xml?

Answer (score 1):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE hibernate-configuration SYSTEM 
"http://www.hibernate.org/dtd/hibernate-configuration-3.0.dtd">

<hibernate-configuration>
   <session-factory>
   <property name="hibernate.dialect">
      org.hibernate.dialect.MySQLDialect
   </property>
   <property name="hibernate.connection.driver_class">
      com.mysql.jdbc.Driver
   </property>

   <!-- Assume test is the database name -->
   <property name="hibernate.connection.url">
      jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/{your-db-name}
   </property>
   <property name="hibernate.connection.username">
      {user-name}
   </property>
   <property name="hibernate.connection.password">
      {password}
   </property>

   <!-- List of XML mapping files -->
   <mapping resource="{your-first-table}.hbm.xml"/>
   <mapping resource="{your-second-table}.hbm.xml"/>

</session-factory>
</hibernate-configuration>
```

Comment: I list like this <mapping resource="{your-first-table}.hbm.xml"/>
   <mapping resource="{your-second-table}.hbm.xml"/> but I got this Error creating bean with name 'sessionFactory' defined in ServletContext resource [/WEB-INF/spring/root-context.xml]: Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is org.hibernate.InvalidMappingException: Could not parse mapping document from resource com/terafast/manager/model/Vacation.hbm.xml

Comment: can u share vacation.hbm.xml?

Comment: Please remove <class name="Vacation" table="vacations">.....</class> from table.hbm.xml

Comment: I already remove that. now I have Vacation.hbm.xml and User.hbm.xml

Comment: I believe i need to see your spring config file along with hibernate config and two hbm files

Comment: my code simply works fine if I use just User.hbm.xml

Comment: can you paste whole exception?

Comment: I should define may User.java class variable as an name of property element in Vacation.hbm.xml